# Are you obligated to study the Zohar?

Tags: torah-study, zohar

Are we Jews obligated to study the Zohar in particular, or at we at liberty to ignore it completely?

(I mean ignore it as part of one's systematic studies.  We obviously never totally ignore it.  Our liturgy includes "Be anna rachitz", a passage from the Zohar.)

Comment: Studying and ignoring are two polar opposites. Perhaps one need not study nor ignore.

Comment: If it is obligatory, you gotta feel bad for all those living 800+ years ago who never heard of it.

Comment: The Talmud wasn't there either 2000 years ago.

Comment: They didn't need the Talmud

Comment: And Rambam felt his Mishneh Torah was the only thing other than Tanach that was required. What are you trying to focus on with this question Maurice? It seems way too open ended. To make a good question you need to tighten this up.

Comment: How about sifri ,sifra,tanchuma,yerushalmi,all the mechiltas ? Why is the Zohar diff ,and if you assume it's not like those mentioned please add to question to better answer your question.

Comment: Do you mean to ask does one need to consider kabbalah or can you just ignore it?

Comment: @mroll That's what Alex is really answering. For many many years until ~800 years ago at least the vast majority of Jews, even learned Jews, hadn't a clue about Kabbala and lived good lives knowing about Halakha only. Whether a specific text was written or not yet doesn't change that, be it the Zohar or the Talmud.

Comment: @DoubleAA You shouldn't delete the comments that refute your false statement above. For those really interested in the truth about this subject, see Responsa 122 in the attached link from Rav Sherira Gaon.  https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30774&st=&pgnum=39

Comment: @Yaacov the comments didn't refute what I said. You agreed with it. You just said we should have pity on the people who lived in those times.

Answer (score 1):

The chayei adam in 10:12 says that one should only learn kalabalah after on "fills his stomach with gemorah and poskim and he is a yeray shemayim and constantly learns torah". So it's not to be ignored but one should be a talmud chacham before proceeding and "if not, don't".

The piskey teshuvos 155 says that Zohar should be part of ones daily learning among mikrah, mishnah, gemora, poskim and mussar. He doesn't mention a prerequisite of being a talmud chacham as the chayei adam does.

Comment: The Hida wrote (Etzba Moreh 44): "Studying the Zohar is the most elevated of studies, even when one does not comprehend what it says and even if one reads it wrong." This is apparently based on the Zohar (3.85), translated as follows: "A person who wishes to study Torah and has found no one to teach him, yet nevertheless studies Torah out of love for the Torah but mumbles it for lack of knowledge-each and every word of his ascends on high, and the Holy One, blessed be He rejoices in each word ... and they are called arvei nahal